# Create a video from a landscape image with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I trying to create a video from a landscape image that moves from left to right of the image.

One form that I thought I can get this done is firstly generating N cropped images from the original one, each of them cropped more and more to the right and then apply some command like this one:

`ffmpeg -framerate 1/X -i img%d.png -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

This for sure works but is not the quickest and cleaning form to do it.
Are there a better method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the crop filter.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 10 -i img.png
       -vf "crop=w=W:h=ih:x='(iw-W)*t/10':y=0"
       -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

The crop filter crops the image to `Wxih` pixels where ih is the original height. You should substitute W with your target width in pixels. The position of the top-left corner of the crop window is set by the x and y expressions.

Since you only want to move left-to-right, y is set to a fixed 0. For x, the expression `(iw-W)*t/10` governs the horizontal position of the crop window. `t` is the processed frame's timestamp in fractional seconds. `W` is substituted with the target width. `iw` is the input width. The crop will start from the left edge and end at the right edge at t = 10 seconds.

---

For an image sequence of 10 seconds, use

```
ffmpeg -i img%d.png
       -vf "crop=w=W:h=ih:x='(iw-W)*t/10':y=0"
       -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Comment: Looks good, the produced video thumbnail looks correct but the duration of the video is near 0. I tried to add :d=10 to the expresion and add -t to the general command and doesn't works.

Current command
```ffmpeg -y -framerate 1/10 -i test.jpg -vf "crop=w=1080:h=ih:x='(iw-1080)*t/10' :y=0" -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p outpanoramic.mp4
```

Comment: The command in your Q implies an image sequence `img%d.png` but you're applying to a single image. I'll modify my command for this case.

Comment: Perfect! It works now. Thank you very much!

I suggest you edit your answer to include both solutions, for one and for several images, perhaps someone find it useful

Comment: @Gyan what if I already made some changes to the video stream in filter_complex and named it [trimmed], how would I make a long input image to overlay from bottom to top and be able to set its speed?

Comment: Post a new Q with your full command.